# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2} = ?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2} = ?$

**Attempt:** $S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2} = \dfrac {2n+2-1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$

$S_1=2  \sum_{n=1}^\infty [\dfrac {n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2} ] - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$

$=2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty [\dfrac {1}{n^2(n+1) } ] - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$

I am stuck on how to move ahead. Please guide me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have $n^2,~(n+1)^1,~$ and $~2n+1.~$ What is the relation between them ? $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}\right]$$
$$=\bigl[\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-\bigl(\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-1\bigr)\bigr]=1.$$

using the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$.

**Otherwise:**

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}$$
>
> $$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-1\right]=1.$$
>
> As, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ is convergent( by p-test) so it cancel out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) . Just one thing though, I think we need not have the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$. By telescoping also, we deduce it

Answer (score 4):

First note that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}\right]$$
By telescoping the series, we can see that
$$
\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\left[1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{9}+\dots +\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\right]
$$
$$
= \lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\left[1-\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\right]=1-0=1
$$